# Remove periods after author initials, but leave spaces

Tags: biblatex

The terseinits option exists to remove the periods after the authors' initials, but it also squashes two or more initials together. How can I have it so that it will be

Author A B, Buthor B C and Cuthor C D

instead of

Author AB, Buthor BC and Cuthor CD

Comment: Just go with `\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}` (and maybe even `\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinithyphendelim}{}`) instead of `terseinits=true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard `terseinits` with Biber is equivalent to

```
 \renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}
 \renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{}
 \renewrobustcmd*{\bibinithyphendelim}{}
```

But you don't want `\bibinitdelim` to be redefined.

So instead of issuing `terseinits=true` you can just use

```
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}
```

and possibly `\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinithyphendelim}{}`

Comment: Random answer to post a link: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion Any thoughts?

Comment: @Johannes_B It's a nice essay for those a bit more familiar with LaTeX (and templates). I'm not too sure if that was the intention though. As a text for (impatient) beginners and users just starting to point out the downsides of using big templates, I fear it might be a bit technical. (Plus, they might not be interested in the "philosophical" discussion in the introduction.)

Comment: @Johannes_B In "Actually, that was made up, but that doesn't mean there is a template out there doing this." do you mean to say "Actually, that was made up, but that doesn't mean there is *no* template out there doing this."?

Comment: It is not complete yet, but it is supposed to be a little: Helpers, let's improve the current situation and help starters. They are searching for templates anyway. Once Tugboat is ready, Barbara will give some input and we can launch it for discussion (maybe mailing list).

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to keep the `terseinits` option and issue

```
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\addspace}
```

in your preamble.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article1,
  title={Journal Article},
  author={A B Author and B C Buthor },
  year={2014},
  journal={Journal}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits,terseinits]{biblatex}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\addspace}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]